# Python - Calling for relative path where csv is stored

Tags: python, relative-path

I have a Dataframe that I would like to save to a csv. I would however like to define the path where the csv is create to be relative. Given below is what I am trying. Could anyone guide me where I am going wrong.

*Path where I am trying to store the csv is **'/users/user/desktop/sample.csv'***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
absolute_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
file_path = absolute_path + '/desktop/sample.csv'
df.to_csv('file_path')
```

Get the below error when executing the above code:

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Could anyone guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: Is there anything wrong? Do you get an error? Which?

Comment: Omit the `''`: `df.to_csv(file_path)`, also `print(file_path)` before that line to make sure it is correct

Comment: It works fine when I give the full path when trying to save the df to a csv file. I however would like to have the path defined and then called when saving the csv file.

Comment: `__file__` is not defined from an interactive interpreter. run from a script it works. Are you running from a script? from an IDE?